# request for member is not a struct or union in C

Tags: c, unix

I have a struct containing an int variable.

```
typedef struct _details_t{
 int id;
 int offset;
 int buff[4];
}details_t;
```

in the main I have attached the shared memory to the pointer which is of structure type as above

```
int set_shm_data(details_t** details){
   if(NULL == details || *details == NULL){
           //error
   }
  *details->id = 345;
  return -1;
}

int main(){
 details_t* shmat;
  ....
  ....
 shmat = (details_t *)shmat(shmid,(void *)0,0);
 if(NULL == shmat){
  //error 
 }

 if(-1 == set_shm_data(&shmat)){
  //error
 }

 return 0;
}
```

I'm getting an error "request for member is not a struct or union" . I have checked the syntax and the calling and accessing methods. Nothing appears to be wrong to get this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
*details->id = 345;
```

The `->` operator binds more tightly than `*`, so you need to use parentheses:

```
(*details)->id = 345;
```